# Regex for a string which contains only number with a length of two and has one white space between them

Tags: python, regex

I am working on validation of inputs and need a regex which take only number with max length of 2 and one white space between them.

Regex for Python

```
import re

pattern="^[0-9_ ]{2}$"

check="01 03"

a=re.match(pattern,check)
if a == None:
    print'Not valid value'
else:
    print"valid value"
```

the output which i get is non valid value, what am i going wrong here

Comment: Try `pattern="[0-9]{1,2}(?: [0-9]{1,2})*$"`. See https://ideone.com/hGU4lt

Answer (score 2):

You're repeating a character set with `{2}`, which will match exactly two of the preceeding token. There will only be a match if the string contains exactly two characters.

Instead, use the character set `[0-9]{1,2}` to match one or two digits, followed by a space, followed by that repeated character set again:

```
[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}$
```

Comment: with this logic if if i check for expression "01 11 101", it gives valid regex, but it should be invalid

Comment: Oops, that's right, need the `^` and `$` anchors as well

Comment: `^` is not necessary, `re.match` only matches at the start of a string.